# Finding nature of composition of function based on the details of component functions

Tags: calculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition, monotone-functions

> If $f:[1,10] \to [1,10]$ is a non-decreasing function and $g:[1,10] \to [1,10]$ is non-increasing function. Let $h(x)=f(g(x))$ with $h(1)=1$, then $h(2)$:
>
> (A) lies in $(1,2)$
>
> (B)is more than $2$
>
> (C) is equal to $1$
>
> (D) is not defined

I know non-decreasing function means the slope is either $0$ or positive and non-increasing function means the slope is either $0$ or negative. I tried to solve this by assuming the function $f$ is increasing and $g$ is decreasing, but ended up at the wrong answer.

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Comment: Hint: $h$ is decreasing and $h(x)\geq{}1$, can you prove this?

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης, $h(x)=f(g(x))$-- g is decreasing and f is increasing. When x increases g decreases and so f decreases. How can $h(x)$ be greater than one. Thank you for replying.

Comment: What if my assumption, considering the functions to be increasing or decreasing be correct. There is also a possibility that they are constant right?

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: @Intellex -- option -- (C) equal to 1.

Comment: Since the codomain of $g$ is contained in the domain of $f$ we have that $h$ is defined for all $x\in[1,10]$. The codomain of $h$ is the codomain of $f$ which is $[1,10]$, so $h(x)\geq 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @FlorisClaassens. I understood everything in your comment except the one - How did you conclude $h(x)>=1?$

Comment: Codomain of $h$ is $[1,10]$, hence $h(x)\in[1,10]$ for all $x$. It follows that $h(x)\geq 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης. That was a silly doubt. If possible will you write your answer. I will accept it.?

Comment: How to conclude $h(x)=1$? @FlorisClaassens. I understood that $h(x)>=1$ but not equal to 1. How to prove it is constant over the interval. Sorry for disturbing again.

Comment: @Sumathi For that you need that $h$ is non-increasing.

Comment: Thank you very much @FlorisClaassens. I understood. I think the author must have phrased a complete question.

Comment: @Sumathi Apologies I was away, I will write the proof for future reference right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x_1<x_2$ then $g(x_1)\geq{}g(x_2) \implies f(g(x_1))\geq{}f(g(x_2))$ which proves that $h$ is decreasing. 
Now $2>1 \implies h(2)\leq{}h(1)=1$ and since $h(x)\in{}[1,10]$ we have $1\leq{}h(2)\leq{}1 \implies h(2)=1$.